# Не устанавливается нужный айтем в комбобоксе WPF

Tags: wpf, combobox

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Coef1" Grid.Column="1"
                            Grid.Row="2"
                                  FontFamily="Dynamics"
                                  FontSize="9"
                                  Foreground="#1B3540"                                 
                                  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=I_Primary_List}"
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding I_Primary}" />
```

Есть код, где выполняется изменение списка I_Primary_List и самого I_Primary. Список меняется, но при этом не устанавливается нужный айтем, а устанавливается пустое. Хотя проверял само значение с эти все нормэ, но вот не устанавливается.

Comment: Вы не правильно настроили биндинг к элементу. Посмотрите [пример](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/explain-combo-box-binding-in-mvvm-wpf/)

Comment: А в чем разница? Зачем мне создавать класс айтемов если мне хватит List<double> ?

Comment: Потому что вы не указали, что у вас в списке I_Primary_List, я предположил, что I_Primary это свойство из списка.  I_Primary_List  список какого типа ? что бы обновлялся он должен быть ObservableCollection Как в том примере, только элементы списка - double для вашего случая, ну и SelectedItem биндить не нужно

Comment: List<double>  I_Primary_List double I_Primary

Comment: Ну так и есть, List не может оповестить ComboBox, о том что его содержимое изменилось. Сделайте вместо листа ObservableCollection<double> I_Primary_List и будет вам счастье :-) да и совет, так именовать I_Primary_List  не принято, это не требование, а рекомендация, но все же вам когда то придется это освоить) На досуге можете посмотреть вот [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines)

Comment: Поменял List на ObservableCollection - не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочий пример. Я думаю вы не установили DataContext. Вообще на будщее, приводите не только код разметки, но и код связанный с этой разметкой. Так ответ был бы значительно быстрее. Сразу скажу, по хорошему желательно вынести работу с PrimaryItems и др. данными в отдельный класс, по паттерну MVVM. И в DataContext указать именно ViewModel класс.

```
 <Grid>
       <ComboBox Width="200" Height="30"
                 FontFamily="Dynamics"
                 FontSize="9"
                 Foreground="#1B3540"                                 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding PrimaryItems}"
                 SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedPrimary}" />
    </Grid>

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<double> PrimaryItems { get; } = new ObservableCollection<double>();

        public double SelectedPrimary { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = this;

            PrimaryItems.Add(0);
            PrimaryItems.Add(1);
            PrimaryItems.Add(2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Нет с контекстом данных все в порядке. В конце концов айтемы есть, просто нужный айтем не выбирается автоматически.

Answer (score 0):

В привязке необходимо использовать `SelectedItem`, а не `SelectedValue`:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding I_Primary}"
```

Comment: Попробовал - все равно не помогает

Comment: В таком случае показывайте код VM или что там у вас

Comment: В консольке есть такой вывод еррора : System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Bold' property not found on 'object' ''Double' (HashCode=1080623104)'. BindingExpression:Path=Bold; DataItem='Double' (HashCode=1080623104);

Comment: Это, видимо, что-то другое ещё у вас сломано